# Funding the American Economy During the Gilded Age

Tags: finance, banking

Does anyone know how John Pierpont Morgan Sr. funded the American economy during the Gilded Age? I'd like to learn about his methods and the significant role he played in shaping the economy through his financial strategies and investments.

Comment: Hi! What exactly do you mean when you write that Morgan Sr. "funded" the "American economy"?

Comment: You can find references to several biographies and specialized studies on his [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._P._Morgan#Specialized_studies). If these are not what you are looking for, can you clarify what it is exactly?